# How to disaggregate records in a table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, geocoding

I'm trying to separate out records in a quasi-summarized table.

Currently, my features are geocoded address points. Each address point has one record associated with it with a field showing how many trees were planted at the property. Most of the time there will only be one tree per property but sometimes there are multiple trees planted at the property.

Ideally I'd like to separate/expand my records so that the number of attribute records for a particular address reflects the number of trees planted at that address.

For example, if property A has 3 tree plantings there will be 3 corresponding records in the attribute table (one-to-many).

If property B has 1 tree planting there will be 1 record in the attribute table.

Is there a tool or workflow that can automate this process??

Comment: did you try pivot tables?